# Calling a subclass in Java polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a superclass Shape.Java that accepts color of a certain shape, and several subclasses that computes the area of different polygons. I created a main class, printing out different choices of polygons that the user wants to compute.

```
public static void choices() {
    System.out.println("What do you want to compute?");
    System.out.println("a. Rectangle");
    System.out.println("b. Triangle");
    System.out.println("c. Trapezoid");
}
```

I used a switch case for this.

```
case 'a': {
    System.out.print("Enter width: ");
    double width = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\nEnter height: ");
    double height = input.nextDouble();
        .....
}
```

Problem is, how am I gonna call my subclass Rectangle(that extends the superclass Shape) that contains the methods that will display the input of the user and compute the area? Is this correct?

```
Shape rec = new Rectangle();
```

If it is, when I compile it I get an error 'cannot find symbol constructor Rectangle...'

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps your `Rectangle` constructor is expecting the width and height as parameters?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it correctly.  Your undefined symbol is probably the result of a bad or non-existent import; Perhaps `Rectangle` is not compiling, or perhaps you do not have a public no-arg constructor on Rectangle.

Because of *dynamic dispatch*, when you do

`Shape rec = new Rectangle();`

The interpreter, at runtime, will look at `rec`, and invoke the method on `Rectangle`, if you are invoking a method that was defined on `Shape` and then overwritten on `Rectangle`.